# Mass mailing Click-Through tracking doesn't include domain in 5.27.3

Tags: wordpress, civimail, click-through

We sent a mass mailing under 5.27.0 (Wordpress) and the email Click Through links were invalid as noted earlier. They did however include our domain.

We upgraded to 5.27.3 and the links are still invalid. They appear to be missing our domain, e.g.

http://?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailing/url&u=674&qid=63201

Comment: I just tried this on 5.27.3 and it worked for me, with a very standard email setup. I added a link, clicked the link when the email arrived and the click thru worked & was recorded by Civi.  What's your email setup?

Comment: Interesting! Our mailer configuration uses mail(). We've not made any recent changes to the CiviMail configuration and it worked prior to 5.27.0.

Comment: My setup is Drupal, should have said that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen this myself (domain missing) but the base page is missing as well from your link.

I'd review the following:

- make sure that the base page is set - go to https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1
- Review the Base Page setting and value, it cannot be blank
- Make sure there is a published page that matches the one in that page
- If there is no value there, add one, civicrm is the default and then create a WP page with that slug
- Make sure the page is public and visiuble to all
- Once you've done that (or confirmed the base page exists) Visit this page https://example.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
- Confirm that your permalinkls are set to anything EXCEPT Plain
- If it is set to Plain change to one of the other options and save
- If it is not set to plain, you can exit the page
- Flush CiviCRM Caches go to https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2FupdateConfigBackend&reset=1  and click cleanup caches

After all that is complete, visit a contribution or event page and be sure it displays.   I'd then try a test email.

Comment: Wow. Adding a blank CiviCRM page in Wordpress made the mass mailing tracking work. (The base page was properly set). I did not expect that.